# R list: add names attribute to each variable element

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply, names

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
> mydf=data.frame(ID=LETTERS, var1=rep(c('a','b'),each=13), var2=c(rep('x',10),rep('y',12),rep('z',4)))
> mydf
   ID var1 var2
1   A    a    x
2   B    a    x
3   C    a    x
4   D    a    x
5   E    a    x
...
```

I want to make a list with the levels of each variable.

Each element in the list should be associated with a `names` attribute.

The names should be identical to the original element. Then I would want the values changed to variable name + original element.

Let me show you what I mean.

I first turn the `data.frame` into the `list` output I want:

```
> mylist=lapply(mydf, unique)
> mylist
$ID
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S"
[20] "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"

$var1
[1] "a" "b"

$var2
[1] "x" "y" "z"
```

Now, I want to add a `names` attribute to the elements, so that names are equal to the original elements, and the new elements are the variable name plus the original elements.

I focus on `var1`:

```
> var1_names=mylist$var1
> var1_values=paste0('var1:',mylist$var1)
> mylist$var1=var1_values
> names(mylist$var1)=var1_names
> mylist
...
$var1
       a        b
"var1:a" "var1:b"
...
```

See how `var1` has changed from:

```
$var1
[1] "a" "b"
```

to

```
$var1
       a        b
"var1:a" "var1:b"
```

Note the `names` attribute and how the new values have changed to include the variable name.

Now I would like to do the same thing for each variable in the list.

Is it possible to do it in a simple way with an `apply` approach and preferably base functions? Thanks!

**EDIT:** The final complete output would look like this (note the `names` attribute in each variable):

```
> mylist
$ID
     A      B      C      D      E      F      G      H      I      J
"ID:A" "ID:B" "ID:C" "ID:D" "ID:E" "ID:F" "ID:G" "ID:H" "ID:I" "ID:J"
     K      L      M      N      O      P      Q      R      S      T
"ID:K" "ID:L" "ID:M" "ID:N" "ID:O" "ID:P" "ID:Q" "ID:R" "ID:S" "ID:T"
     U      V      W      X      Y      Z
"ID:U" "ID:V" "ID:W" "ID:X" "ID:Y" "ID:Z"

$var1
       a        b
"var1:a" "var1:b"

$var2
       x        y        z
"var2:x" "var2:y" "var2:z"
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost in the explanation, but do you want something like `cols <- c("var1","var2")` then `Map(paste, mydf[cols], names(mydf[cols]), sep=":")` as an output?

Comment: not really... the important thing is that each variable has a names attribute and the elements are each unique level (along with the var name)

Comment: let me edit to clarify the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
lapply(names(mydf), \(x) paste(x, unique(mydf[[x]]), sep = ":"))

[[1]]
 [1] "ID:A" "ID:B" "ID:C" "ID:D" "ID:E" "ID:F" "ID:G" "ID:H" "ID:I" "ID:J" "ID:K" "ID:L" "ID:M" "ID:N" "ID:O" "ID:P" "ID:Q" "ID:R" "ID:S" "ID:T" "ID:U" "ID:V" "ID:W" "ID:X" "ID:Y" "ID:Z"

[[2]]
[1] "var1:a" "var1:b"

[[3]]
[1] "var2:x" "var2:y" "var2:z"
```

To add a name attribute you can use `setNames()`:

```
lapply(
  names(mydf), 
  \(x) {
    elm = unique(mydf[[x]])
    setNames(paste(x, elm, sep = ":"), elm)
  }
)
```

Comment: I really like this approach with base functions thanks! this would be my preferred option. There is still a couple things missing, if you can help me with... the imap function works great! but that only solves half of my problem... I'd need var names (ID, var1, var2), as well as a `names` attribute for each of the var sub-elements (without the `var::` part)

Comment: See my last edit with how the final complete output should look like

Comment: just tried, this is exactly what I need! many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Update: With the help of @akrun (many thanks):

We could do:

```
mydf %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ list(str_c(cur_column(), unique(.x), sep = ":")))) 

# or 

imap(mydf, ~ str_c(.y, unique(.x), sep = ":"))
```

You mean this?

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("var"), ~paste0(cur_column(),":", .)))
```

```
   ID   var1   var2 value
1   A var1:a var2:x     1
2   B var1:a var2:x     2
3   C var1:a var2:x     3
4   D var1:a var2:x     4
5   E var1:a var2:x     5
6   F var1:a var2:x     6
7   G var1:a var2:x     7
8   H var1:a var2:x     8
9   I var1:a var2:x     9
10  J var1:a var2:x    10
11  K var1:a var2:y    11
12  L var1:a var2:y    12
13  M var1:a var2:y    13
14  N var1:b var2:y    14
15  O var1:b var2:y    15
16  P var1:b var2:y    16
17  Q var1:b var2:y    17
18  R var1:b var2:y    18
19  S var1:b var2:y    19
20  T var1:b var2:y    20
21  U var1:b var2:y    21
22  V var1:b var2:y    22
23  W var1:b var2:z    23
24  X var1:b var2:z    24
25  Y var1:b var2:z    25
26  Z var1:b var2:z    26
```

Comment: hmmm not quite there yet... the important thing for me is that each variable has a names attribute and the elements are each unique level (along with the var name)

Comment: let me edit to clarify the explanation

Comment: @TarJae Perhaps you want `mydf %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ list(str_c(cur_column(), unique(.x), sep = ":"))))` or `imap(mydf, ~ str_c(.y, unique(.x), sep = ":"))`

Comment: Thanks! the `imap` function works great! but that only solves half of my problem... the other half would be to apply a `names` attribute to each of the vars in the list, so that the names attribute do not contain the `var::` part

Comment: Just added an edit with how the complete final output should look like